# Can't find Google Maps mapview.myLocation (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I show the user's location on the map with Google Maps iOS SDK?

I try to find `.myLocation` property in `self.myMapView(MKMapView)` but I can't find it.

Can anyone explain me step by step how to show my user's location on the map?

Comment: `MKMapView` is the Apple Maps map view - the Google Maps map view is `GMSMapView`.

Answer (score 2):

Create properties for GMSMapView and CLLocationManager like

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var didFindMyLocation = false

and in the viewdidload method add observer for map view for location update like below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(48.857165, longitude: 2.354613, zoom: 2.0)
        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView.delegate = self

        mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

    }

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if !didFindMyLocation {
            let myLocation: CLLocation = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

            didFindMyLocation = true
        }
    }
```

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }
}
```

didFindMyLocation is the bool property, and also don't forget to add the 'NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription' key to Info.plist file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code will set marker to desired coordinated.
Current location coordinates you can get via CoreLocation framework(CLLocationManagerDelegate)

```
self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 6)

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
marker.title =   "Marker title"
marker.map = self.mapView
```